# Should I worry if 'pkexec' is in a cPanel user's /home/virtfs (CVE-2021-4034)?

Tags: centos, security, cpanel, pkexec, virtfs

The recent security bug CVE-2021-4034 in Linux involves `/usr/bin/pkexec`. Following media reports (zdnet, etc.) I changed its permission, but also found this file:
`/home/virtfs/foo/usr/bin/pkexec` for cPanel user `foo`.

I don't know why a user would have `pkexec` shadowed.

Unfortunately we are running an outdated WHM/cPanel (with root) on outdated CentOS 6, until we can migrate the last sites off it.

Answer (score 0):

VirtFS is the cPanel implementation of a jailed shell. It works with hardlinks to binaries. `pkexec` running in a jailed environment can still communicate with the polkit daemon RPC mechanisms and as such is still a risk.